# How to retrieve daily running and walking steps from Google Fit API

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

It is probably a newbie question but I have lost a one day to figure out w/o success.
I'm using Google Fit API into my Android app and I need to show some of its data like running and walking daily steps. I have managed to show data but in time unit (f.e running in x min). I need to show it in steps unit.

The snipped below code shows how I retrieved data as time unit (in milliseconds):

```
  DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT, DataType.AGGREGATE_ACTIVITY_SUMMARY)
            .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .setTimeRange(start, end, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();


  Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(client, readRequest).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataReadResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DataReadResult dataReadResult) {
            if (dataReadResult.getBuckets().size() > 0) {
                display.show("Bucket DataSet.size(): "
                        + dataReadResult.getBuckets().size());
               retrieveHistoryData(dataReadResult, client.getContext());
             }
        }

                            .....

   private void retrieveHistoryData(DataReadResult dataReadResult, Context context) {

    int walking = 0;
    int running = 0;
    int biking = 0;

    for (Bucket bucket : dataReadResult.getBuckets()) {
        List<DataSet> dataSets = bucket.getDataSets();
        for (DataSet dataSet : dataSets) {
            display.show("dataSet.dataType: " + dataSet.getDataType().getName());
            for (DataPoint dp : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
                 walking += getBucketData(dp, FitnessActivities.WALKING);
                 running += getBucketData(dp, FitnessActivities.RUNNING);
                 biking += getBucketData(dp, FitnessActivities.BIKING);
            }
        }
    }

    Log.d(TAG, Constants.KEY_WALKING_STEPS + ": " + walking);
    Log.d(TAG, Constants.KEY_RUNNING_STEPS + ": " + running);
    Log.d(TAG, Constants.KEY_BIKING_STEPS + ": " + biking);
}

private int getBucketData(DataPoint dp, String activityName) {
    int count = 0;
    for (Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Field " + field.getName() +  " " + FitnessActivities.getName(dp.getValue(field).asInt()) + " = " + dp.getValue(field).asInt() + " field.describeContents()" + field.describeContents());
        if ("activity".equals(field.getName()) && activityName.contentEquals(FitnessActivities.getName(dp.getValue(field).asInt()))) {
            count +=  dp.getValue(field).asInt();

        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Tnx in advance.

Best regards

MB

Comment: "For example, pass in the TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA data type to this method to retrieve the daily total steps. You may pass in an instananeous data type that has a respective aggregate daily total. For more information on the supported data types, see [AGGREGATE_INPUT_TYPES](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataType#AGGREGATE_INPUT_TYPES)."

Comment: Tnx for quick replay. Sorry, but I didn't see any type which match my requirements. I need running and walking activities daily data shown in steps unit. Like in the Google Fit app.

Answer (score 2):

You can get steps for various activities for each day by using the following code

```
DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .aggregate(ESTIMATED_STEP_DELTAS, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .bucketByActivityType(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();
```

where ESTIMATED_STEP_DELTAS is defined as

```
DataSource ESTIMATED_STEP_DELTAS = new DataSource.Builder()
            .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .setType(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
            .setStreamName("estimated_steps")
            .setAppPackageName("com.google.android.gms")
            .build();
```

You can run this code in a loop to get data for as many days as you want. It will return data buckets for all activities that have steps involved and you can fetch activity name from the bucket by this method that returns activity name as String

```
bucket.getActivity();
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: It is too late for the actual person who asked this question but I hope it helps someone else who's facing similar issue. :)